# initdb /usr/local/var/postgres on El Capitan

Tags: macos, postgresql, osx-elcapitan

I'm attempting to run `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres` after installing postgresql 9.5 via homebrew on El Capitan but I get the following:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "kyledecot".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /usr/local/var/postgres ... initdb: could not change permissions of directory "/usr/local/var/postgres": Operation not permitted
```

When attempting to `cd /usr/local/var/postgres` I get:

```
cd: permission denied: /usr/local/var/postgres
```

It appears that I don't have the proper permission to do this. I assume this has something to do w/ El Capitan's [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) but I could be wrong.

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`` sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local ``

Comment: Thank you for sharing the full `chown` syntax

Answer (score 10):

I had to combine two bits of advice that I have seen with Stack Overflow questions related to this question/error. I found myself in a chicken and an egg situation where I would reinstall postgres and change permissions one at a time, but both commands conflicted with each other.

So I did this:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local && brew postinstall postgresql
```

...and it worked fine.

Comment: The command should use "postinstall" rather than "post install"

Answer (score 2):

I find it not really efficient and secure to `chown` all `/usr/local` directory, so I did simply

    `mkdir /usr/local/var/postgres`

And all went smooth.

Comment: I had a stale install of PostgeSQL with Homebrew, uninstalling it, removing all postgresql files I found with `find / -name postgres` and then `mkdir /usr/local/var/postgres` got me a happy install.